# Is there a way to daisy-chain SSH commands using ssh config?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh, ssh-agent

I am trying to SSH from a docker container to a remote server. The docker container is on a Mac. All the authentication to connect to the remote server is done from the Mac, not the docker container.

Therefore it is not possible to do

```
ssh -J host.docker.internal remote-server
```

It is however possible to daisy chain the ssh commands like this

```
ssh -tt host.docker.internal ssh remote-server
```

I want to be able to edit the ssh config on the docker container so I can simply do

```
ssh remote-server
```

I have tried all the usual directives and cannot get it working.

Interestingly one of the configs I've tried is as follows...

```
Host remote-server
  ProxyCommand ssh -tt USER@host.docker.internal ssh USER@%h
```

Then executing `ssh -v remote-server` shows the command I want to run but the terminal just hangs and no connection is established

```
root@bc9912af3ad4:~/.ssh# ssh -v USER@remote-server
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -tt USER@host.docker.internal ssh USER@remote-server
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
^C
root@bc9912af3ad4:~/.ssh#
```

Comment: Not sure I'm fully understanding your question, but you may be looking for the `RemoteCommand` directive. Possible content of your `.ssh/config` file, following `Host remote-server`: `RequestTTY yes`, `Hostname host.docker.internal`, `RemoteCommand ssh remote-server`.